# Which is the best Cross-Platform Framework for mobile app development?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, cross-platform

Hi i wanna start develop Cross platform application for mobile app (mostly for Tablets/iPad). which one is the best in below to start with :

- Appcelerator
- Phonegap
- Xamarin
- Mosync

Answer (score 2):

Each framework has its own Con's & Pro's.

Choosing a Framework is purely based on your selection criteria like :

- Availability across different platforms
- Development
- Speed
- UI
- Performance